# What do the characters on this CCTV lens mean?

Tags: lens

There are 3 controllable rings on the CCTV lens.
Each ring has 2 characters on them with the ring farthest from the sensor being F and N.
Next is O and C. The last ring is T and W.

What does each of these characters represent?
The O and C controls the aperture, so I'm assuming it stands for open and close.
I'm guessing the F and N stands for far and near. I have to adjust that and the W and T ring for the camera to focus.[image: CCTV Lens]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"W"ide and "T"elephoto - i.e. they will control the zoom - as opposed to "N"ear and "F"ar which control the focus.

Comment: O for Open, C for Closed?

Comment: I believe so. The diaphragm opens up and closes in relation to that particular ring.

Answer (score 5):

The descriptive text on the lens says "2.8-12mm" so this is a zoom lens. Therefore you have three controls, aperture, focus and zoom.

I would be pretty sure that the markings are

- **W**ide/**T**elephoto (zoom)
- **O**pen/**C**losed (aperture)
- **N**ear/**F**ar (focus)

On most lenses there is some cross-coupling between the focus and zoom. Changing one will have some effect on the other.